# How to declare array of strings inside Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to `split` the `string` based on `;` and store it in array of `string` in `MVC Razor view` and I tried it as below:

```
@{
     string[] replies = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(messages.MessageReply) ? messages.MessageReply.Split(';') : new string []{};
}
```

But whenever I write this it will treat last `}` of the `string[] replies` as its main closing bracket instead of the one below. How can I avoid this or how would I be declaring such sort of variables in razor view?

Comment: Works fine for me. But that sort of code should be in a controller (and set the value of a view model property), not in the view

Comment: So @StephenMuecke.. This isn't possible here?

Comment: As I noted, your code works fine. What is the error your getting?

Comment: Error in the sense its treating the very next `}` bracket as closing bracket for `@{`.. Like if I use `messages.MessageReply.Split(new []{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` it treats `}` inside `split` as closing bracket as it will be highlighted with yellow color..

Comment: Using `.Split(new []{';'}` works fine for me as well. I suspect there are other issues with your code (I can create a simple DotNetFiddle if you need the proof)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Would you mind if I ask you to create one for my reference.. :)

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c0wzTx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105558/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Yea.. it works fine in DEMO.. Not sure about my problem.. Anyways.. Thanks for the demo buddy.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pust conditional expression into brackets:

```
string[] replies = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messages.MessageReply) ? messages.MessageReply.Split(';') : new string []{ });
```

Or... just get rid of brackets:

```
string[] replies = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(messages.MessageReply) ? messages.MessageReply.Split(';') : new string [0];
```

It should help

Comment: That would be problem if I include `messages.MessageReply.Split(new []{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`!!

Comment: So, you must have an other issue in your code. As I said, I've checked yout scenario and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use: `string[0]` instead of `string[]{}`:

```
@{
     string[] replies = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(messages.MessageReply) ? messages.MessageReply.Split(';') : new string [0];
}
```